# Laravel - log out specific user

Tags: authentication, laravel, logout

I know how to log in a user, but how do I log out a specified user from the application? There doesn't seem to be enough coverage on this.

Comment: You means user logout from your application when they click user logout button?

Comment: No, I want to manually log out a specific user from within my controller, for example `Auth::logout($user)` or something between those lines.

Answer (score 6):

This problem occures when you are admin and want to block some user. Then when you block user you want to logout him imidietly. For laravel 5.2 (maby for lower versions too) you can create middelware:

Create middelware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class BockedUser
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if ($user and $user->is_bocked) {
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect('/login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And in app/Http/Kernel.php in section $middlewareGroups > 'web' add \App\Http\Middleware\BockedUser::class. I assmue that all your routes are in `Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () { .. all your routes ..}`

Comment: anything better than this ?

Answer (score 3):

If you know his user id, using query builder,

**// To Logout Specific user:**

```
//$id == user id to whom you want to logout
\DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->update(['remember_token' => null]);
\DB::table('sessions')->where('user_id', $id)->delete();
```

**// To Logout All Users**

```
$sessions = glob(storage_path("framework/sessions/*"));
foreach ($sessions as $file) {
if (is_file($file))
unlink($file);
}
\DB::table('users')->update(['remember_token' => null]);
\DB::table('sessions')->truncate();
```

No need to use sessions table operation if you are not using database as session driver.

Comment: Thanks for this example, deleting a row in the "sessions" table alone won't work - it will be automatically inserted again on user's next request. Clearing the "remember_token" column is the important part.

Answer (score 2):

### Use the setUser to find a soluion

**get current user**

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

**logout user you want**

```
$userToLogout = User::find(5);
Auth::setUser($userToLogout);
Auth::logout();
```

**set again current user**

```
Auth::setUser($user);
```

Comment: Auth::logout() will just logout the current user not the specific one.

Comment: yeah, but you have to set a user as current user

Comment: Just stumbled on this answer that is the most correct, but where @ImadUllah says "**set again current user**" you must use the current user id, fetching it first `$your_current_user = User::find(YOUR_DESIRED_USER_ID_HERE);` and then calling `Auth::loginUsingId($your_current_user->id)`. This way you will not be logged out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for logout specific user logout in laravel 4.2 and you are using multi auth

```
/* for normal user logout */
 Auth::user()->logout();

 /* for admin user logout */
 Auth::admin()->logout();


/* for manager user logout */
 Auth::manager()->logout();
```

as you made the users auth

Answer (score 0):

You can logout user when he access any authenticated function such as edit profile, edit post, create post, etc. For example:

```
   public function edit()
   {
      if (!\Auth::user()->active)
      {
        \Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');
      }
      // code here
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in the middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!auth()->user()->is_approved) {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->route('unauthorized');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Just to add some context.